# Adobe illustrator Scripting (JavaScript) Beginner Questions

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I am literally 24 hours into learning javascripting for Adobe Illustrator and I have two basic questions:

Firstly, is there a way to clear the contents of a document prior to re-running the same script.  Currently I'm creating a new document each time with the following command:

```
var docX = 595, docY = 842;
var doc = documents.add(null, docX, docY);
```

Is it possible to write to the same document by preceding the above code with something like:

```
documents.clear()
```

rather than creating a new document each time?

Secondly, I'm a little confused by the Javascript syntax. Is there only one way to initialize JavaScript objects? Currently I'm using the following syntax:

```
var c0 = new RGBColor; 
c0.red = 255; 
c0.green = 255; 
c0.blue = 255;
```

but shouldn't the following also work?:

```
var c0 = new RGBColor(255, 255, 255);
```

It doesn't for me.

Many thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that your code for adding document is wrong, it should be like

```
var docX = 595, docY = 842;
var doc = app.documents.add(null, docX, docY);
```

For your first part, yes you can clear contents of documents as below

`app.documents[0].pageItems.removeAll();`  // Remove all items from documents.

After adding one document, you can run above line it will clear contents of documents and document will be blank and you can use that document without adding new document

For your second part,

```
var c0 = new RGBColor(255, 255, 255);
```

is not correct, because this is not the syntax for javascript.

Since you are learning Illustrator scripting, here is the link for javascript reference for Illustrator. You can go through the documentation and learn

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015_3/Illustrator%20JavaScript%20Scripting%20Reference.pdf

Hope this will help you in learning more. Enjoy..